# LINQ filter list by nested collection

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following class hierarchy:

```
public class SportPlan
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Record> RecordFields { get; set; }
}

public class Record
{
    public Guid Key { get; set; }
    public string Alias { get; set; }
    public List<Value> Values { get; set; }
}

public class Value
{
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public List<DayOfWeek> DaysOfWeek { get; set; }
}
```

I need to filter `SportPlan.RecordFields` by `dayOfWeek`(.NET enum)and get list of `Value`s using LINQ.
I tried something like this but it does not work:

```
var filtredExercises = SportPlan.RecordFields.Select(x => x.Values.Where(v => v.DaysOfWeek.Equals(dayOfWeek))).ToList();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `Select`, you need to use `Where` to filter your list. Something like this should be close to what you want:

```
var filteredExercises = SportPlan.RecordFields
                                 .Where(f => f.Values.Any(v => v.DaysOfWeek.Contains(dayOfWeek)))
                                 .ToList();
```

This would give you all `Record`s that have a `Value` where `DaysOfWeek` contains the `dayOfWeek` you're looking for.

If instead you need the `Value` objects, you could use something like this:

```
var filteredExercises = SportPlan.RecordFields
                             .SelectMany(f => f.Values)
                             .Where(v => v.DaysOfWeek.Contains(dayOfWeek))
                             .ToList();
```

With [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.8), we first flatten the list of lists of `Value` objects to a `IEnumerable<Value>` and then filter that using the `dayOfWeek`.

Comment: But if I need the list of `Value`s instead of `Record`s?

Comment: @MichaelKostiuchenko I updated my answer, please have a look.

Comment: @MichaelKostiuchenko you should clarify this point: "But if I need the list of Values instead of Record" in your post and edit it accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var filtredExercises = SportPlan.RecordFields.Select(x => x.Values.Where(v => v.DaysOfWeek.Equals(dayOfWeek)).Length > 0 ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match on any existing item in the list of DaysOfWeek, try this:

```cs
var filtredExercises = SportPlan.RecordFields.Select(x => x.Values.Where(v => v.DaysOfWeek.And(d => d.Equals(dayOfWeek)))).ToList();
```